# What is right way to use select directive in angular.dart

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I extend angular.dart.tutorial with basic CRUD operations. So in new edit_recipe_component.html I need to add some sort of selection input for recipe categories.

Currently I have

```html
<select ng-model="ctrl.recipe.category">
   <option ng-repeat="c in ctrl.categories" value="{{c}}">{{c}}</option></select>
```

That works perfectly well on the surface: I can select category from the list, selected category is successfully stored in model and so on.
But I get these errors in debug console:

```
NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'ngValue'
Receiver: null
Arguments: []

STACKTRACE:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:42)
#1      _SingleSelectMode.onModelChange.<anonymous closure> (package:angular/directive/input_select.dart:185:78)
#2      _SelectMode._forEachOption (package:angular/directive/input_select.dart:146:24)
#3      _SingleSelectMode.onModelChange (package:angular/directive/input_select.dart:183:19)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Unfortunately [APIDOCS to InputSelectDirective](http://ci.angularjs.org/view/Dart/job/angular.dart-master/javadoc/angular.directive/InputSelectDirective.html) has no usage section

**Update**: I've created github project based on Chapter 6 sample where problem is reproduced
 It is here: https://github.com/vadimtsushko/angular_tutorial_chapter_06

Some debugging shows that setting category in Edit form works immediately and successfully (I've added category in Recipes list view for debug purpose).
Error raised when I leave Edit form.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Works for me without that error.

Comment: Thank you, I've published sample reproducing error on github.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this issue has been fixed for a while (hence no need for a patch), but in any case, you could also have used `ng-value`:

```html
<select ng-model="ctrl.recipe.category">
   <option ng-repeat="c in ctrl.categories" ng-value="c">{{c}}</option></select>
```

Answer (score 2):

do a little patch on `_SingleSelectMode` class in [input_select.dart](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/blob/master/lib/directive/input_select.dart)

```dart
onModelChange(value) {
    var found = false;
    _forEachOption((option, i) {
      if (option == _unknownOption) return;
      if (expando[option] == null ) return;
      var selected = value == null ? option == _nullOption : expando[option].ngValue == value;
      found = found || selected;
      option.selected = selected;
    });
```